# Quelle est la différence entre "rédiger" et "écrire" ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, verbes

Quand utiliser le verbe **rédiger** et quand utiliser le verbe **écrire**? quand je peux les échanger

Comment: [Écrire](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9E0358); [Rédiger](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9R1104)

Comment: "Rediger" suggest you already know what you are going to write , while " écrire" suggests that you are looking for a way to express what you want to say. 

One would not say " Le policier a écrit un procès-verbal".

Comment: Also, you will rarely hear " bien rédigé", but rather " bien écrit".

Comment: @RayLittleRock « Écrit » n'est pas très idiomatique pour les procès : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A9crit+un+proc%C3%A8s+verbal%2Cdress%C3%A9+un+proc%C3%A8s+verbal&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdress%C3%A9%20un%20proc%C3%A8s%20verbal%3B%2Cc0.« Dresser » est très souvent le verbe utilisé.

Comment: c'est ce que je disais précisément, on dira plutôt , " rédiger un procès verbal" ou, mieux, " dresser"

Comment: "C'est bien écrit" is used very often, either referring to someone's handwriting (for example for pupils at school), or to someone's writing style. In the latter use, it is interchangeable with "c'est bien rédigé".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Écrire est une action générique, dénuée de toute tentative de sens. On peut très bien écrire sans but, ses initiales sur une table en bois.

Rédiger implique une construction préalable, un plan, une narration. Un CV, une lettre, un rapport.

Answer (score 0):

Selon moi, écrire est plus général que rédiger: je peux écrire une liste de courses. La rédiger demanderait une tournure d'esprit plus [oulipienne](https://www.cairn.info/revue-poetique-2011-4-page-415.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Pour savoir quand il est possible d'échanger ces deux mots:

- si l'on fait référence à la construction d'un texte, on peut utiliser indifféremment **écrire** ou **rédiger**: "j'ai écrit un article" / "j'ai rédigé un article"
- si l'on fait référence à l'acte physique d'écriture, on utilise **écrire** seulement: "j'ai écrit l'alphabet", "j'ai écrit mon nom", "j'ai écrit sur la feuille"

En résumé, **rédiger** implique un effort mental, **écrire** ne l'implique pas.

Comment: La question demande?

Comment: L'expression s'emploie mais elle n'est pas très heureuse, je modifie.